Integer solutions for $2abcd=(a+2)(b+2)(c+2)(d+2)$.
I started with only $2$ variables so that the problem was $2ab=(a+2)(b+2)$, which was easy to do as I could just graph it using $x$ and $y$ variables instead which gave me the two pairs: $a=4,b=6$, and $a=3,b=10$.
I then went straight to $3$ variables and found $20$ solutions and then $4$ variables (the question of the title) and found 373 solutions but not with certainty as it could be $374$. I think this is from the integer sequence $A263207$ as that is the closest sequence I could find from my limited data.
What makes this problem special I think is the visual representation as if you make an ab rectangle and a $(a+2)(b+2)$ rectangle and place the $ab$ rectangle on top of the bigger rectangle. Then it would look like a ring around the $ab$ rectangle, and a box incasing an $abc$ cuboid but it gets hard to visualise the $4$th dimensions tho so this is the closes visualisation I can think of.
I'm not looking for negative integers as there can be an infinite amount of them like $a=-2$, $b=0$, $c=\text{anything}$ and $d=\text{anything}$, if this problem already has a name please tell me.

Fun fact: with $k$ variables, the numbers $2k$, $2k+2$, $2k+4$, $4k-2$ will always be a solution. I've posted a method for finding the full set of solutions for $k=4$, which can be extended to arbitrary $k$, but it's not very elegant. Does anyone know if there's a way of finding the number of solutions for arbitrary $k$?

The LaTeX you want is \le for less than or equal to (by the way, you can right-click on any formatted equations and Show Math as TeX commands to see these). It's usually easier to count these in order, because it makes the space much smaller; then you can use permutations and combinations to count the unordered solutions, if you want to.

i forgot to add that a\le b\le c\le d, otherwise there would be around 8,952 solutions, idk if thats easier tho

First divide through and rewrite the equation as
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{b}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{c}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{d}\right)=2$$
It's usually a good idea with these problems to put $a,b,c,d$ in order and establish some bounds so you don't have too large a space to search.
Let's say $a\le b\le c \le d$, so that $1+\frac{2}{a} \ge 1+\frac{2}{b}$ etc.
Then
$$2 = \left(1+\frac{2}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{b}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{c}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{d}\right)\le \left(1+\frac{2}{a}\right)^4$$
ie
$$1+\frac{2}{a}\ge \sqrt[4]{2}$$
which leads to $a\le 10$.
I'm afraid it's case bashing after that: for each value of $a$, you can repeat this process to get a set of possible $b$ values, and so on.

thanks, I never thought of doing this thanks for the technique and I just found out that A263207 is the integer sequence I'm looking for anyways

If all $a,b,c,d \geq 11$, then we have that $$2abcd = \prod_{cyc}(a+(\sqrt[4]{2}a-a)) > \prod_{cyc}(a+2) =(a+2)(b+2)(c+2)(d+2)$$

Here are some solutions for $a,b,c,d\le 20:$
$[5,14,16,18],  [5,14,18,16],  [5,16,14,18],  [5,16,18,14],  [5,18,14,16],  [5,18,16,14],  [6,10,16,18],  [6,10,18,16],  [6,11,13,20],  [6,11,20,13],  [6,12,14,16],  [6,12,16,14],  [6,13,11,20],  [6,13,20,11],  [6,14,12,16],  [6,14,16,12],  [6,16,10,18],  [6,16,12,14],  [6,16,14,12],  [6,16,18,10],  [6,18,10,16],  [6,18,16,10],  [6,20,11,13],  [6,20,13,11],  [7,10,12,18],  [7,10,18,12],  [7,12,10,18],  [7,12,12,14],  [7,12,14,12],  [7,12,18,10],  [7,14,12,12],  [7,18,10,12],  [7,18,12,10],  [8,10,10,18],  [8,10,12,14],  [8,10,14,12],  [8,10,18,10],  [8,12,10,14],  [8,12,14,10],  [8,14,10,12],  [8,14,12,10],  [8,18,10,10],  [9,10,11,13],  [9,10,13,11],  [9,11,10,13],  [9,11,13,10],  [9,13,10,11],  [9,13,11,10],  [10,6,16,18],  [10,6,18,16],  [10,7,12,18],  [10,7,18,12],  [10,8,10,18],  [10,8,12,14],  [10,8,14,12],  [10,8,18,10],  [10,9,11,13],  [10,9,13,11],  [10,10,8,18],  [10,10,18,8],  [10,11,9,13],  [10,11,13,9],  [10,12,7,18],  [10,12,8,14],  [10,12,14,8],  [10,12,18,7],  [10,13,9,11],  [10,13,11,9],  [10,14,8,12],  [10,14,12,8],  [10,16,6,18],  [10,16,18,6],  [10,18,6,16],  [10,18,7,12],  [10,18,8,10],  [10,18,10,8],  [10,18,12,7],  [10,18,16,6],  [11,6,13,20],  [11,6,20,13],  [11,9,10,13],  [11,9,13,10],  [11,10,9,13],  [11,10,13,9],  [11,13,6,20],  [11,13,9,10],  [11,13,10,9],  [11,13,20,6],  [11,20,6,13],  [11,20,13,6],  [12,6,14,16],  [12,6,16,14],  [12,7,10,18],  [12,7,12,14],  [12,7,14,12],  [12,7,18,10],  [12,8,10,14],  [12,8,14,10],  [12,10,7,18],  [12,10,8,14],  [12,10,14,8],  [12,10,18,7],  [12,12,7,14],  [12,12,14,7],  [12,14,6,16],  [12,14,7,12],  [12,14,8,10],  [12,14,10,8],  [12,14,12,7],  [12,14,16,6],  [12,16,6,14],  [12,16,14,6],  [12,18,7,10],  [12,18,10,7],  [13,6,11,20],  [13,6,20,11],  [13,9,10,11],  [13,9,11,10],  [13,10,9,11],  [13,10,11,9],  [13,11,6,20],  [13,11,9,10],  [13,11,10,9],  [13,11,20,6],  [13,20,6,11],  [13,20,11,6],  [14,5,16,18],  [14,5,18,16],  [14,6,12,16],  [14,6,16,12],  [14,7,12,12],  [14,8,10,12],  [14,8,12,10],  [14,10,8,12],  [14,10,12,8],  [14,12,6,16],  [14,12,7,12],  [14,12,8,10],  [14,12,10,8],  [14,12,12,7],  [14,12,16,6],  [14,16,5,18],  [14,16,6,12],  [14,16,12,6],  [14,16,18,5],  [14,18,5,16],  [14,18,16,5],  [16,5,14,18],  [16,5,18,14],  [16,6,10,18],  [16,6,12,14],  [16,6,14,12],  [16,6,18,10],  [16,10,6,18],  [16,10,18,6],  [16,12,6,14],  [16,12,14,6],  [16,14,5,18],  [16,14,6,12],  [16,14,12,6],  [16,14,18,5],  [16,18,5,14],  [16,18,6,10],  [16,18,10,6],  [16,18,14,5],  [18,5,14,16],  [18,5,16,14],  [18,6,10,16],  [18,6,16,10],  [18,7,10,12],  [18,7,12,10],  [18,8,10,10],  [18,10,6,16],  [18,10,7,12],  [18,10,8,10],  [18,10,10,8],  [18,10,12,7],  [18,10,16,6],  [18,12,7,10],  [18,12,10,7],  [18,14,5,16],  [18,14,16,5],  [18,16,5,14],  [18,16,6,10],  [18,16,10,6],  [18,16,14,5],  [20,6,11,13],  [20,6,13,11],  [20,11,6,13],  [20,11,13,6],  [20,13,6,11],  [20,13,11,6]
$.
